# TFS2010 workspaces get corrupt after unshelving Rename+add

Tags: version-control, tfsbuild

We use TFS2010 source control, gated check-in and build services. To save time, we use incremental build (Clean Workspace = None).

Recently, a developer did the following in his Visual Studio 2010:

- Rename MyClass.cs to Base.cs
- Add new MyClass.cs

He tried to checkin this. However, the gated checkin build failed in the "Get Workspace" step with:
`BuildError: The auto merge option is not supported for the conflict on item .`

After that, the build agent's workspace appeared to remain in some inconsistent state. Other people's checkins produced all kinds of weird build errors on other files that were included in that shelveset.

To work around, we eventually deleted the workspace manually, and that solved the issue (we could've also temporarily set Clean Workspace = All).

So:
Is this - shelveset with rename+add SC operations corrupts workspaces - a known issue?

Comment: Curious, have you disabled "clean workspace" in the build definition?

Comment: similar issue with work around here,  [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/4622518f-e914-428f-aa53-c66a3b953121) - might help ?

Comment: I'm aware of "Clean workspace" - edited to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

We developed this problem with the .sql files for our database project. It had been working fine, then out of the blue we started seeing this error (the C# files caused no issues).

I set "Clean Workspace = All" as alluded to by Betty in the OP's comments and ran a test check-in. That seemed to fix things. I reset "Clean Workspace = Output," as I'd had before, and things seem to be working fine now.